# window.stop() in Chrome 61

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have code that stopped page unloading. It works in version 60, but does not work in 61. Do you know anything about this? How i can stopped page unloading at new version?

Simplistic, it looked so:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
  window.stop();
})
```

Comment: Pretty sure that never worked? If a website could unilaterally stop a user from closing a page, that would be a serious problem.

Comment: `window.stop()` stops the page from loading, not from unloading. It's equivalent to using the stop button

Comment: I made mistake, code looked so:

`$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {

  setTimeout(function () {
    window.stop()
});
})
`

`window.stop()` called asynchronous, and it works

Comment: it doesn't work - You mean a different thing. Stopping unload means you stop the page from exiting, which is impossible